# Android: Removing a List Item on CheckBox-Click checks next Item

Tags: android, listview, adapter

i have a weird behavior. I have a to-do-list-like function where i remove a ListView Item when the CheckBox is clicked. However, this causes the next Checkbox to be checked instantly.
Any idea?

```
@Override
public void onCheckBoxClick(int position) {

    mTaskList.remove(position);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

It is like the click gets carried over to the next Item, because the Item is removed so fast.

**EDIT:**

This is the CustomAdapters getView() method. Its an RPG themed task list.

```
 @NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    View taskItemView = convertView;
    if (taskItemView == null) {
        taskItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.task_item, parent, false);
    }

    TaskItem currentTaskItem = getItem(position);

    //set all Item Texts accordingly
    TextView taskName = (TextView) taskItemView.findViewById(R.id.task_name_xml);
    taskName.setText(currentTaskItem.getName());
    TextView difficultyText = (TextView) taskItemView.findViewById(R.id.task_difficulty_xml);
    difficultyText.setText(currentTaskItem.getDifficultyText());
    TextView expGainText = (TextView) taskItemView.findViewById(R.id.exp_win_xml);
    expGainText.setText("" + currentTaskItem.getExpAmountGained() + " EXP");
    TextView goldGainText = (TextView) taskItemView.findViewById(R.id.currency_win_xml);
    goldGainText.setText("" + currentTaskItem.getGoldAmountGained());
    CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) taskItemView.findViewById(R.id.task_checkbox_xml);
    checkbox.setChecked(false);
    //set Checkbox Listener

    checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mListener.onCheckBoxClick(position);
        }
    });

    return taskItemView;

}
```

Comment: Its difficult to guess from this bit alone. Check your getView() function - you must be incorrectly setting the checked state when refreshing the list.

Comment: But i dont set the checked state at all in the getView() method. An i only have this effect on the next item in the row. It is like the clicks "outlives" the item removal and gets carried over to the next item. 
If i set the checkbox to unchecked in the getView() method, it checks it for a short moment and then unchecks it immediatly.

Comment: Ah then that is the problem - you should set the checked state in the getView method, or the recycled views will contain the old checked status. Always refresh each element in your row inside the getView method. Its hard to say more than this without seeing your full adapter code.

Comment: Well, thats works, it just looks a bit weird, because its checked for a brief moment. But if there is no other way, then its ok like that.

Comment: It shouldn't take time for the system to call getView unless you're doing something inside it that takes a long time. Can you add your getView() method to the question?

Comment: I edited it in. I set some texts and an onClickListener.

Answer (score 1):

There are few things you need to change.

1. Always use the Recycled view pattern for listviews. Its faster and a lot more memory efficient

Add a View holder class for your Task:

```
class TaskViewHolder
{
    TextView taskName;
    TextView difficultyText;

    TaskViewHolder(View root)
    {
        taskName = (TextView) taskItemView.findViewById(R.id.task_name_xml);
        difficultyText = (TextView) taskItemView.findViewById(R.id.task_difficulty_xml);
    }
}
```

Then change your getView() like this:

```
TaskViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.task_item, parent, false);
        holder = new TaskViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
        holder = (TaskViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

    TaskItem currentTaskItem = getItem(position);

    holder.taskName.setText(currentTaskItem.getDifficultyText());
    holder.difficultyText.setText(currentTaskItem.getDifficultyText());
return convertView;
```

I have only included 2 of your views but you get the idea.

2. When you set the oncheckchanged listener set it like this:

   holder.checkBox.setTag(position);
   holder.setOnClickListener(this);

Then inside your onClick(View v) callback do this:

```
//check if this is the correct view
int position = (int)v.getTag();
TaskItem t = getItem(position);
//do what you like here
```

Again, I haven't included all the views in the holder, so you should add them. This should fix your issue.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I have to look into ViewHolder, because i dont know it yet. I set up my Adapter according to the Android Tutorial on Udacity. I will do that tomorow and then comment here (its 5 am right now)

Comment: Thank you. But i dont understand the onClickListener part, is there some sort of typo? Is also crashing when i try to add more than 1 item to the list.

Comment: You could either use an OnClickListener or an OnCheckedChangeListener to get callbacks when the checkbox is clicked. Implement the relevant interface on your Adapter class instead of using an anonymous class within the getView() method. Then you can write: holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: Also, don't ever use "final position" inside a click listener as the value of "position" changes as you scroll down. Always use "setTag" and then "getTag" inside the callback to get a reference to the corresponding list entry.